# Pointer type casting

Tags: c, pointers

I know pointer of one type can be casted to pointer of another type, for example when using malloc the void pointer can be casted to another type. But I've seen this piece of code which casts a value directly into a pointer type. Could you help me to understand what is going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum otype {INT, SYM, CONS};
typedef struct obj {
  enum otype type;
  struct obj *p[1];
} obj;

int 
main(void)
{

  struct obj *o1 = (obj *) 10;
  printf("%d\n", (int) o1);

  struct obj *o2 = (obj *) "abc";
  printf("%s\n", (char *) o2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, you don't cast a `void*` pointer to another type. That's the point, why `malloc` returns a `void*` so it can be assigned directly to the required type of pointer. Also why `memcmp` takes `void*` arguments, so you can pass any type.

Comment: What you are doing with your casts, is to hide a poor use of pointers from the compiler. And what is the purpose of the one-element array `struct obj *p[1];`?

Comment: Again the comment posted below.  I think the point of the code above is that the pointer will not be dereferenced; rather, it will be that obj can hold enum type INT, SYM, etc. and the array inside it will point to (obj *) 10 or (obj *) "abc"; then later these values can be retrieved back by converting again using (int) or (char *). That's how I understand it. But I've not seen this kind of using pointer before so I'm asking about what's going on and if I'm wrong on or missing anything

Comment: In `printf("%s\n", (char *) o2);` the pointer *is* dereferenced (by `printf`). It's just as well you haven't seen this use of pointers before, and hopefully you won't see it again. If you want to interpret in different ways, use a *`union`*.

Comment: What about the (int)?

Comment: Well I fail to see the point of placing an `int` value in a pointer so you can later use that `int` value. And consider what will happen if you try that technique when you have a 32-bit pointer and a 64-bit `uint64_t`.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a bit more about this? Thanks!

Comment: I mean that if you put a 64-bit int value into a 32-bit pointer value, you might not get the whole value back. Apart from that there is nothing to explain that a good tutorial on pointers can't do better. They are not intended to be used like this, end of.

Comment: I don't understand how this could have happened with the above code, unless the native int type is 64 bit and obj * is 32, but I think this is not possible to happen right?

Answer (score 0):

You can freely cast any pointer type, as well as some non-pointer types, into any other pointer. This does not mean that the result has any useful meaning.

A pointer is just an integer that contains the memory address of some piece of data. When you cast it from one type to another, what you're actually doing is telling the compiler that the same number (memory address) refers to a different type. Depending on the source and destination types, the result may range from useful to completely and utterly meaningless.

Taking your example:

```
struct obj *o1 = (obj *) 10;
```

This tells the compiler to treat memory address 10 (0xa) as if it contains a struct of type obj. Since, in all likelihood, memory address 10 does not contain that, trying to actually dereference that pointer will result in undefined behavior.

```
struct obj *o2 = (obj *) "abc";
```

Here we are on slightly firmer grounds (not much). This is because, even though we do not know what is the address that `o2` got, we do know what's in that memory. That memory contains the sequence `0x61 0x62 0x63 0x00`. Assuming a little Endian machine (which most of them are these days), this means that your enum contains the (invalid) value 6513249, and your pointer is as undefined as it was in the first case.

Comment: Hi, I think the point of the code above is that the pointer will not be dereferenced; rather, it will be that obj can hold enum type INT, SYM, etc. and the array inside it will point to (obj *) 10 or (obj *) "abc"; then later these values can be retrieved back by converting again using (int) or (char *). That's how I understand it. But I've not seen this kind of using pointer before so I'm asking about what's going on and if I'm wrong on or missing anything.